# allocate a value to a new data dable by reference where count of group is over a specific number

Tags: r, data.table

```
enrolments<-data.table(ID=c(100001, 100001, 100001, 100001, 100002,  
100002, 100002, 100002),
start_date=c("Jan-10","Jan-10","Jun-10","Jun-10", "Jan-10","Jan-11","Jan-11","Jun-11"),       
subject_code = c(1:8), 
status = c("Pass","Fail","Withdrawn","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass","Pass"))
```

I have a data.table of enrolments with student_IDs, start dates, subject code, status (pass, withdrawn, fail).

> ID start_date  subject_code    status
>   1  100001  Jan-10  1   Pass
>   2   100001  Jan-10  2   Fail
>   3   100001  Jun-10  3   Withdrawn
>   4   100001  Jun-10  4   Pass
>   5   100002  Jan-10  5   Pass
>   6   100002  Jan-11  6   Pass
>   7   100002  Jan-11  7   Pass
>   8   100002  Jun-11  8   Pass

I would like to create a new column "first_subjects" where if the status of the first TWO subjects is withdrawn or fail the column = Y, otherwise = N

The data is already sorted by student and date

Comment: The required answer was produced. This is perfect, can now look at relationship between that a failure in the first n subjects results and course discontinuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
 enrolments[, first_subjects:=c('N', 'Y')[any(status[1:2] %in% 
                         c('Fail', 'Withdrawn'))+1] , by=ID]

 enrolments
 #       ID start_date subject_code    status first_subjects
 #1: 100001     Jan-10            1      Pass              Y
 #2: 100001     Jan-10            2      Fail              Y
 #3: 100001     Jun-10            3 Withdrawn              Y
 #4: 100001     Jun-10            4      Pass              Y
 #5: 100002     Jan-10            5      Pass              N
 #6: 100002     Jan-11            6      Pass              N
 #7: 100002     Jan-11            7      Pass              N
 #8: 100002     Jun-11            8      Pass              N
```